# How to define a skewed distribution using mode and two inflection points?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, python, algorithms, skew-normal-distribution

I want to define a skewed distribution function and plot it in python using the mode and inflection points parameter values instead of using the mean and standard deviation.

For example, I have `mode=110` and `inflection points = (40, 160)` for asymmetrical points.

Or `mode=100` and `inflection points = (50,150)` for symmetrical points we can define gaussian normal distribution in this case.

I tried with this code below for gaussian function, but I don't how I can add the second point to the formula which is returned by the function? Since I have two points, and I don't know how to define a skewed function that depends on two points and mode.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
def distribution(x, mode, inf_point):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*inf_point)*np.exp(-np.power((x - mode)/inf_point, 2)/2)
x = np.linspace(0,256)
plt.plot(x, distribution(x, mode, inf_point))
```

Comment: This version suffers from the same incomplete description as the original.  Please edit the original question to explain more clearly what you're trying to do.  In particular, why do you want to use *three* parameters to describe a distribution family given by the *two* parameters "mean" and "standard deviation"??